# How do I fix the push sidebar menu CSS?

Tags: css, menu

I have a problem with a push sidebar menu. When the toggle button is clicked the page goes to the right .The problem is that I want the side bar menu to be next to the page just like the example that is in the picture . Also when i scroll down to the page ,I want the side bar menu to be fixed. I am only using css.

```css
@media (max-width: 575px) {

    .navbar-brand {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .slideout-sidebar {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        left: -80%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #fff;
        transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset -15px 0px 10px -15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        box-shadow: inset -15px 0px 10px -15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);


    }


    .slideout-sidebar ul li {
        display: block !important;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 10px 10px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #0d6490;
        margin: 0;
       
    }

    .slideout-sidebar button {
        font-size: 1rem !important;
        width: 220px;
        height: 37px;

    }

    .navbar-brand {
        width: 12rem;
        height: 3.2rem;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }

    .container-content {
        position: relative;
        left: 0px;
    }

    #menu-toggle {
        display: none;
    }


    .menu-icon {
        position: fixed;
        top: 5px;
        left: 5px;
        font-size: 35px;
        z-index: 1;
         transition: all.15s ease-in-out;
        padding: 5px 15px;
        background-color: transparent;


    }

    #menu-toggle:checked ~ .slideout-sidebar {
        left: 0;
    

    }

    #menu-toggle:checked + .menu-icon {
        left: 250px;
        

    }

    #menu-toggle:checked ~ .container-content {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(80%);
        transform: translateX(80%);
        transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
    }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle" class="menu-icon" />
        <label for="menu-toggle" class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-bars mt-2"></i></label>

        <div class="container-content">
            <header>
                <div class="header-container d-flex justify-content-around container-fluid">
                    <div class="slideout-sidebar order-1">
                        <ul class="d-md-flex flex-md-column flex-lg-row mt-md-4">
                            <li class="brd mr-md-2 align-self-center menu">МЕНИ</li>
                            <li class=" order-lg-last btn-order"> <button class="btn" type="submit">НАРАЧАЈТЕ
                                    ВЕДНАШ</button></li>
                            <li class="brd border-bottom border-top border-primary d-none ">КОНТАКТИРАЈТЕ НЕ</li>
                            <li class="brd d-none">УСЛОВИ ЗА КОРИСТЕЊЕ</li>
                            <li class=" border-bottom border-primary d-none brd">РЕСТОРАНИ</li>
                            <li class="order-lg-first mr-md-4 text-center brd align-self-center">
                                <a class="">МК</a>
                                <div class="d-inline-block 
         language-line"> | </div>
                                <a class="">EN</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mx-auto mx-lg-0 mt-2">
                        <img src="./images/logo.png" alt="dominoslogo" class="navbar-brand" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="cart mt-2">
                        <img src="images/basket.png" alt="basket" class="d-lg-none">
                        <span class="header-cart-order d-lg-none">0</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </header>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Sarah. You should update the code in your question so that it reproduces the problem (so when we click "Run code snippet" we more or less see what's in the image you've provided). For example, it looks like you're using Bootstrap, but that's not in your snippet. You could also replace images with placeholders from placeholder.com. It's hard to tell what the real issue is with the current state of the question.

Comment: Here you go maybe this will help. https://codepen.io/sb90mng/pen/wvaGpJa .When i click on the toggle icon there is a white space between the menu and the content.